# Why does simple Promise statement not work in browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to pass a promise value to the next promise and wrote the line below to test it out.

```
Promise.resolve('hey').then(console.log);
```

simple enough, if I run node(4.3.0) in terminal I get the desired outcome

```
> Promise.resolve('hey').then(console.log);
Promise { <pending> }
> hey
```

However this is not the result I'm getting in browsers.

Firefox doesn't error out, but never logs "hey";

```
Promise.resolve('hey').then(console.log);
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
>
Promise.resolve('hey').then(console.log);
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
>
```

Chrome bugs out even more

```
Promise.resolve('hey').then(console.log);
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

With no stack trace.

I tried to see if Babel would translate this code to something else but It does not change this statement at all.

What gives? 
Will this break if I use these statements in my code too?

Comment: `Promise.resolve('hey').then(x => console.log(x));`

Comment: Note that you can see the missing error in Firefox by using `catch` (but you have to use `console.log` correctly in `catch` in order to see it!): `Promise.resolve('hey').then(console.log).catch(x=>console.log(x));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just pass `console.log`, you need to call it directly with the value(s) you want to log:

```
Promise.resolve('hey').then(function(s) { console.log(s); });
```

Comment: its a function is it not? ... why?

Comment: @lonewarrior556 calling a function as a method (`foo.bar()`) supplies the owning object as a `this` value to the function. When you call the same method in a different way, it runs with a different `this` value. To see this, do `bar=function(){return this;}; foo={bar:bar}; console.log(foo.bar(), bar())`. The `then` method does not invoke `log` as a member of `console`, which `log` requires.

Comment: ahhhh, should have googled it, but I didn't realize the console.log was the issue.